# Ansible conditionally loop through with_items?

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to loop through a list of items if a string is defined in a variable i will specify. 
Essentially i want to have a list of variables defined and utilized the aws_s3 module to download the files only if they are defined when running the playbook

e.g

say i have the list "var1,var2"

and I have the following variables defined:

`apps_location:
  - { name: 'vars1', src: 'vars1.tgz', dest: '/tmp/vars1_file.tgz' }
  - { name: 'vars2', src: 'vars2.tgz', dest: '/tmp/vars2_file.tgz' }
  - { name: 'vars3', src: 'vars3.tgz', dest: '/tmp/vars3_file.tgz' }`

Task:

`- name: "Splunk Search Head | Download Splunk Apps from S3"
    aws_s3:
      bucket: "{{ resource_bucket_name }}"
      object: "{{ item.src }}"
      dest: "{{ item.dest }}"
      mode: get
    with_items: "{{ apps_location }}"`

I want to run the command: 
ansible-playbook -i inventory -e "var1,var2"

and download only var1 and var2 on that specific run.

I tried utilizing "lookups" but couldnt get the syntax right. Im not entirely sure if this best way of doing this, but i want to have a predefined list of file locations and only download the ones that i'm passing during runtime.

Note the only reason "name" exists in apps_location is to see if i can do a lookup and only install that one but i couldnt get the syntax right.

---

Define a variable containing a list of defined apps. I'm trying:

```yaml
- name: "Set Fact"
  set_fact:
    dict: "{{ apps_location[item].dest }}"
  with_items: "{{ my_vars|default([]) }}"
```

However whenever I output dict I only get the last value.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `extra-vars` must be an assignment of a variable and value. For example

```sh
shell> ansible-playbook -i inventory -e "my_vars=['vars1','vars2']"
```

A more convenient structure of the data would be a dictionary for this purpose. For example

```yaml
apps_location:
  vars1:
    src: 'vars1.tgz'
    dest: '/tmp/vars1_file.tgz'
  vars2:
    src: 'vars2.tgz'
    dest: '/tmp/vars2_file.tgz'
  vars3:
    src: 'vars3.tgz'
    dest: '/tmp/vars3_file.tgz'
```

Then the loop might look like

```yaml
  - aws_s3:
      bucket: "{{ resource_bucket_name }}"
      object: "{{ apps_location[item].src }}"
      dest: "{{ apps_location[item].dest }}"
      mode: get
    loop: "{{ my_vars|default([]) }}"
```

---

Q: *"Define a variable containing a list of defined apps."*

A: Try this

```yaml
- set_fact:
    my_list: "{{ my_list(default([]) +
                 [apps_location[item].dest] }}" 
  loop: "{{ my_vars|default([]) }}"
```

<sup>(not tested)</sup>

Comment: Extra vars was a typo but wow thanks! Such a simple solution, not sure why i went i attempted so many complex things.

Comment: Going to try to sneak another question as its related. I'm now trying to take the list of defined apps and define a variable containing a list of defined apps.
so I'm trying:
` - name: "Set Fact"  set_fact:      dict:        apps_location: "{{  apps_location[item].dest }}"    with_items: "{{ my_vars|default([]) }}`
However whenever I output dict.apps_location i only get the last value. Any idea how i can concatenate them into a list and define that as dict.apps_location? The main background here is im integrating into an existing ansible playbook and need to define that var

Comment: I've updated the answer and the question. Open new questions if you have more issues. Make it [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Avoid comments for this purpose! Delete the comments.